# How to read ACTUAL CSS rule for border radius

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am wrapping an auto-generated div around an image, and I need to apply some styling from the image to the div.

How can I read/get the CSS rule for border-radius that is affecting the image?

For example, if the CSS is setting the border-radius to `30px`, it should return "30px", and if it's `50%`, it should return "50%" - ***I want the actual rule, not just a pixel value***

[image]

Comment: clone class name of Image to Div

Comment: The selector that is setting the border radius affects all `<img>` tags inside a certain wrapper - it does not apply to a class name

Comment: $('.element img').css('border-radius')

Comment: It returns an empty string @user3801433

Comment: POst your html structure

Comment: If i use `.css('border-top-left-radius')` it returns a pixel value, but `.css('border-radius')` returns empty string

Comment: then there is no `border-radius` style. it should be `border-top-left-radius` in the question.

Comment: Anonymous downvoters ll answer you.

Comment: @MarcoPrins works for me ... http://jsfiddle.net/Rhumborl/twto6fza/1/

Comment: @Rhumborl that is definitely *not* working in my browser (Firefox). I need a cross-browser solution

Answer (score 2):

```
$el.css('border-radius');
```

where `$el` is the jQuery object of the generated `div`.

http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/qfpuLekt/1/

Comment: I didn't downvote, but `$el` is not a valid selector, it should rather be something like `$('.el').` which defines the class "el"

Comment: If anybody didn't understood that "$el is the Jquery object of the generated DIV." then it is really a sorry place to post an answer.

Comment: Are there Moderators around?...or its just a farce going on.

Comment: @Azrael, you can save a jQuery object as a variable. `var $el = $('.el');` then you can use `$el` throughout your project without needing to search for that element during
 every action.

Answer (score 0):

Using `.css()` jquery method you can get the actual value. You can use it like below.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
     alert($("#testing img").css("border-radius"));
  });
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qfpuLekt/)

Comment: As this is identical to the preceding two answers, I am now really puzzled why, if this works (which it appears to), that they were down-voted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code i wrote to get the actual text of a css rule:

```
function getCssRule(selector, ruleName) {
    var classes = document.styleSheets[0].rules || document.styleSheets[0].cssRules;
    for (var x = 0; x < classes.length; x++) {
        if (classes[x].selectorText == selector) {
            if(classes[x].cssText){
                var text = classes[x].cssText.substr(classes[x].cssText.indexOf(ruleName));
                text = text.substr(text.indexOf(':')+1, text.indexOf(';') - text.indexOf(':') - 1);
                if(text[0] == " ")
                    text = text.substr(1);
                return text;
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log(getCssRule('.class', "margin"));
```

There are some problems that come with the css handling that make it difficult to use: 
1. if your document contains multiple stylesheets, the index of the used stylesheet depends on the insertion of your rules (mostly it's 0)
2. the browsers might handle some rules differently and refactor them (for example in chrome the border-radius get's split up into border-top-left-radius, border-top-right-radius, border-bottom-left-radius and border-bottom-right-radius)

working fiddle: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o8vhve09/)